# How to stop one IntentService while there are many IntentService are running

Tags: android, service, download, intentservice

I have a listview contains many songs. Each time a song is clicked, I call an IntentService to download this song by sequence.

But sometimes I want cancel a download (for example: the 5th). It means I need to stop the 5th running IntentService. I attempt to stop it by call stopService() but it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me a good way to stop IntentService? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I would guess that by that you kill the first random process - can this be proved? If so, then you need to indentify the PiD of each one of the processes, I'm not quite sure how to do that, but give me some time and I think I can find something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is only one running `IntentService`, per `<service>` element in your manifest. If you call `startService()` six times, at most one `IntentService` will be running. Commands will queue up and be processed one at a time by `onHandleIntent()`, if the `IntentService` is processing a command when another command is sent.

In your case, since you cannot readily cancel an outstanding command with `IntentService`, you will probably need to create your own version of `IntentService`, where you create your own `Service` subclass with its own work queue, one where you have the ability to cancel commands that are not yet running.

Comment: Yes, it seems the best way to fix my problem.

Comment: IntentService has internally a queue and will server serially all of them. So I think that the best solution for you is to use a Service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while downloading using intentservices.
In my app, each download has its own notification, and when clicking on it I want to stop the download.

I solved it by overriding the onStartCommand() method (called when a new intent arrives).
When I wanted to close one download, I started a new intent with an extra called "stopid":

```
Intent stopIntent = new Intent(DialogActivity.this,DownloadIntentService.class);
stopIntent.putExtra("stopid", id);
startService(stopIntent);
```

The onStartCommand() method looks like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int id = intent.getExtras().getInt("stopid");
    if(id!=0) {
        stopList.add(id);
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

For normal intents, just put the id of your download in your intent as an extra.
While doing the download in the onHandle() method, check often if the stopList contains the id of your current download intent. If it does, stop downloading and remove the id from the stopList.

Comment: In the latest android reference, it is noted that this method should not be overridden. What are the risks if note is ignored and the issue original poster mentioned is solved using your method?